# Set browser cookie one day

Tags: javascript, html, session, cookies

I successfully create a webpage with a Age Confirmation Block Popup. I code like popup appears once per user, appears a single time for everyone. But i want to make as like it appears 1 time each day. Cookie with reset per 24 hour.
Can anyone please suggest any idea to how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

```
<a onClick="document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display='none'; setCookie('abc', 'def', 365)" href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">OK</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
        {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name)
        {
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
          }
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_value = null;
          }
        else
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
          var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
          if (c_end == -1)
          {
        c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
        return c_value;
        }


        if(getCookie('abc')=="def" && document.getElementById('ac-wrapper'))
        document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display='none';
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
setCookie('abc', 'def', 365)
```

to

```
setCookie('abc', 'def', 1)
```